# Converting app.config to code in VB.NET or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I am trying to convert the following app.config in to VB.NET:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="MessageEncoding" type="MessageEncodingElement, Server" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="MessageEncoding">
          <MessageEncoding  contentEncryption="All" contentCompression="GZip" />
          <httpTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>    
    <services>   
      <service name="ExampleService" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/Example" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MessageEncoding" contract="IExampleService" >
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Behavior">
          <serviceAuthenticationManager serviceAuthenticationManagerType="AuthenticationManager, Server"/>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" >
            <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="AuthorizationPolicy, Server" />
            </authorizationPolicies>
          </serviceAuthorization>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have tried the following, but I am missing something:

```
Dim host As ServiceHost
Dim bindingElements As ICollection(Of BindingElement) = New List(Of BindingElement)()
Dim ServerMessageEncodingElement As New MessageEncodingBindingElement

ServerMessageEncodingElement.ContentEncryption = "All"
ServerMessageEncodingElement.ContentCompression = "GZip"

Dim httpBindingElement As New HttpTransportBindingElement()

bindingElements.Add(MessageEncodingElement)
bindingElements.Add(httpBindingElement)

Dim binding As New CustomBinding(bindingElements)
Dim endpoint As ServiceEndpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IExampleService), binding, "http://example/Example")
Dim col = New ReadOnlyCollection(Of IAuthorizationPolicy)(New IAuthorizationPolicy() {New AuthenticationManager()})
Dim sa As ServiceAuthorizationBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find(Of ServiceAuthorizationBehavior)()

If sa Is Nothing Then
    sa = New ServiceAuthorizationBehavior()
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(sa)
End If

sa.ExternalAuthorizationPolicies = col
```

I have tried multiple versions of the above, I can place other tries if needed. I just need to get this out the door. Answers in C# or VB.NET are welcome.

Comment: What kind of problem are you having? A compile error? Functionality error?

Comment: Functionality, I can not get my head round the programmatic code, the xml seems straight forward. I am just not sure what the code is for the above functionality in the XML. I have been trying for a few days to get it working. I have a standard wcf interface using http or tcp. I am trying to replace an old .net remoting example that used rsa keys for authentication and found the following page: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166044/WCF-Client-Server-Application-with-Custom-Authenti - Now I am trying to get that working with no app.config file. I pass in the URI from another application.

Comment: So there is no need for an app.config, and the application will be obfuscated and have added protections for class names etc, so it would be better to have the wcf config inside the application

Comment: basic tcp or http wcf is not a problem, its just that my manager would like the functionality found in the link provided above, ie Database roles, Database Usernames, rsa encryption etc etc.

Comment: Have you checked MSDN for all of the elements listed above? I believe most of them will have some coding equivalents that you could model off of. Such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthenticationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have implementing a class based of off of the above mentioned link and have overridden the correct methods and my code works fine using the app.config, but I have been unable to find am example of programmatically using it to build the wcf servicehost in code without declaring it in the app.config xml. I am finding it quite hard to find examples that don't use the app.config xml configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ExampleService));
ICollection<BindingElement> bindingElements = new List<BindingElement>();
ServerMessageEncodingBindingElement ServerMessageEncodingElement = new ServerMessageEncodingBindingElement();
ServerMessageEncodingElement.ContentEncryption = ContentEncryptionType.All;
ServerMessageEncodingElement.ContentCompression = ContentCompressionType.None;
HttpTransportBindingElement httpBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
bindingElements.Add(ServerMessageEncodingElement);
bindingElements.Add(httpBindingElement);
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(bindingElements);
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IExampleService), binding, "http://" + My.Computer.Name + "/Example");
dynamic col = new ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy>(new IAuthorizationPolicy[] { new ChallengeAuthorizationPolicy() });
ServiceAuthorizationBehavior sa = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceAuthorizationBehavior>();
sa.ExternalAuthorizationPolicies = col;
sa.PrincipalPermissionMode = PrincipalPermissionMode.Custom;
ServiceAuthenticationBehavior sm = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceAuthenticationBehavior>();
sm.ServiceAuthenticationManager = new ChallengeAuthenticationManager();
host.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim host As New ServiceHost(GetType(ExampleService))
     Dim bindingElements As ICollection(Of BindingElement) = New List(Of BindingElement)()
        Dim MessageEncodingElement As New MessageEncodingBindingElement()
        ServerMessageEncodingElement.ContentEncryption = ContentEncryptionType.All
        ServerMessageEncodingElement.ContentCompression = ContentCompressionType.None
        Dim httpBindingElement As New HttpTransportBindingElement()
        bindingElements.Add(MessageEncodingElement)
        bindingElements.Add(httpBindingElement)
        Dim binding As New CustomBinding(bindingElements)
        Dim endpoint As ServiceEndpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IExampleService), binding, "http://" & My.Computer.Name & "/Example")
        Dim col = New ReadOnlyCollection(Of IAuthorizationPolicy)(New IAuthorizationPolicy() {New AuthorizationPolicy()})
        Dim sa As ServiceAuthorizationBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find(Of ServiceAuthorizationBehavior)()
        sa.ExternalAuthorizationPolicies = col
        sa.PrincipalPermissionMode = PrincipalPermissionMode.Custom
        Dim sm As ServiceAuthenticationBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find(Of ServiceAuthenticationBehavior)()
        sm.ServiceAuthenticationManager = New AuthenticationManager
        host.Open()
```

Answer to the above question